# How should I Parse and Delay a Hot Reactive Extensions IConnectableObservable<T> stream?

Tags: datetime, system.reactive

I am unable to implement this, so unfortunately I have no Rx code to show where I am at. I will explain what i would like t do, and hopefully someone out there with enough expertise might be able to guide me in the right direction.

Let us say that I have a collection of List TimeObjects that I pulled from a database. TimeObject has this form.

```
public class TimeObject
{
   public    DateTime time{get;set;}
   public    decimal  price{get;set;}
}
```

What I want to do is produce a Hot IConnectableObservable stream, where each element is separated  by a variable time delay.

The variable time delay is equal to the difference between the time of the current and the next TimeObject.

For example, if the stream is this:

s1, s2, s3, ...sN, where each 's' represents an element of TimeObject

Then, the time delay before s2 is pushed out to the stream is (s2.time - s1.time), 
the time delay before s3 is pushed out to the stream is (s3.time - s2.time) and so on.

Is this at all possible, and if so, what should my implementation look like?

I have included a for loop that accomplishes the same task using a classical approach.

```
        FireEvent(TimeObject[0]); //Post the first element as an event

        for(int _counter = 0; _counter < TimeObject.Count; _counter++)
        {
            if ( _counter + 1 < TimeObject.Count )
            {
                TimeObject timeObjectA = TimeObject[_counter];

                TimeObject timeObjectB = TimeObject[_counter + 1];

                int millisecondsDelay = (timeObjectB.time - timeObjectA.time).Milliseconds;

                Thread.Sleep(millisecondsDelay);

                FireEvent(timeObjectB);   //this posts the latest tick as an event with variable time delay.
            }
```

What I would like is for this to be converted into an Observable stream.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            1,
            x => x < timeObjects.Count,
            x => x + 1, x => timeObjects[x],
            x => timeObjects[x].time.Subtract(timeObjects[x - 1].time)))
        .StartWith(timeObjects[0]);
```

Now, this is a regular cold observable. You could make it hot by calling `.Publish()`. Why do you need it hot?

It also requires your list to have at least two elements

Comment: Thank you for this nice, cold, tasty example. I need it hot because I want it to produce notifications even if there are no subscribers. I intend to have multiple subscribers connected, and have them receiving the same data at the same time. Seeing that I will need at least two elements in order to perform the subtraction, I would simply place a check to ensure there are at least two elements available. Cheers :)